# I want to analyze WCF messages

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-security

as in title I want to see the code of the messages exchanged in local testing.

I want to do it to ensure that they are really encrypted as I set to do.

Can someone help me?

Thanks,

Alberto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [SvcConfigEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732009.aspx) to enable tracing, which may be enough - see also (on MSDN) [Configuring Message Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx). Alternatively - for non-local testing, you can perhaps use something like Fiddler (for http) or Wireshark (for everything else) to watch the traffic.

Answer (score 5):

Try this Microsoft util :

[Service Trace Viewer Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx)

Handy for diagnosing exactly what is going on under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes use [SoapTrace](http://soaptrace.sourceforge.net/) - its fairly lightweight but you have to use HTTP transport.